# Regular expression for validating numeric(6,2)

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using SQL Server 2008. I have a numeric column for numeric(6,2).
For which I have a regular expression for 6 digit number with optional 2 decimal digit:

```
[RegularExpression(@"^\d{0,4}(\.\d{0,2})?$", ErrorMessage = "Must be number with maximum 2 decimal places & maximum 7 characters.")]
public decimal? PALLET_W { get; set; }
```

This allow all the below values:

1234.34, 345.45, 45.5, 4.5, 1234

But, It does not allow these values: 123456, 12364.7

My main requirement is maximum 7 characters with optional 2 decimal digit.

So, I need to allow these values too: 123456, 12364.7

Is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you

```
^\d{1,6}(\.\d{1,2})?$
```

You can test it [here](https://regex101.com/r/fY1vM1/3).

**Edit**

For that (total 6 digits max), use this

```
^\d{1,4}((\d{1,2})|(\d\.\d)|(\.\d{1,2}))?$
```

Check [here](https://regex101.com/r/fY1vM1/5).